# concerns module of controllers as shared with concerns module of models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, module, activesupport-concern

if I create a FooConcern module in controllers/concerns folder and FooConcern module in models/concerns, there is a override problem, or we can use them like disinct module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is yes. 
So I add "Controller" in name of concerns's controllers to avoid duplicate name class.